# oledb Diffrent mysql columns in one textbox with if command

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement, ole

i'm messing aroung with my new tool i creating at the moment. I got a little problem and dont know how i can get the problem solved. I'm using ole db (accdb file) and a listbox.

So here is my problem:

i've got a quest table

there are a tables named like a_prize_type0 to a_prize_type4 which values are for example 0 (item), 1(gold), 2(exp).

then i got other tables with names like

a_prize_index ( for item ) so if a_prize_type0 = 0
a_prize_data0 (for gold) so if a_prize_type0 = 1
and so on.

No i want to put all these prize values in one textBox and the type in another box.!

So if a_prize_type0 = 0 i want that a_prize_index0 is displayed in box 2 and in box 1 the type is displayed
and if a_prize_type0 = 1 i want that a_prize_data0 is displayed in box 2 and in box 1 the type is displayed

My Code:

try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from quest where a_name='" + listBox1.Text + "'";
                command.CommandText = query;

```
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                textBox28.Text = reader["a_prize_type0"].ToString();
                textBox29.Text = reader["a_prize_index0"].ToString();
                textBox30.Text = reader["a_prize_data0"].ToString();
                textBox31.Text = reader["a_prize_type1"].ToString();
                textBox32.Text = reader["a_prize_index1"].ToString();
                textBox33.Text = reader["a_prize_data1"].ToString();
                textBox34.Text = reader["a_prize_type2"].ToString();
                textBox35.Text = reader["a_prize_index2"].ToString();
                textBox36.Text = reader["a_prize_data2"].ToString();
                textBox37.Text = reader["a_prize_type3"].ToString();
                textBox38.Text = reader["a_prize_index3"].ToString();
                textBox39.Text = reader["a_prize_data3"].ToString();
                textBox40.Text = reader["a_prize_type4"].ToString();
                textBox41.Text = reader["a_prize_index4"].ToString();
                textBox42.Text = reader["a_prize_data4"].ToString();
                textBox64.Text = reader["a_prize_data1"].ToString();
                textBox63.Text = reader["a_prize_data2"].ToString();
                textBox65.Text = reader["a_prize_data3"].ToString();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
```

I hope some understands what i mean >.<

And Thx For that awesome community! And all the people who help me!!
and sry for my bad eng.

Comment: Please post your code?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange at the moment i only put the values from the database in many textBoxex with textBox28.Text = reader["a_prize_type0"].ToString(); and so on

Comment: @PoweredByOrange i edited my code from my listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event